# Identification of Mold / Fungus

Tags: bacteriology, mycology, health

I am working with some old plaster powder, and a few days after it set (mixed with water), I found that pink mold / fungus appears to be growing on it. See attached photo.

Please help me identify what type of mold this is and if it is dangerous to my health.

Thank you.

[image: fungus]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Personal medical questions are [off-topic here.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It would be useful to include your geographic location.